# Symfony3.2 to symfony4 security.encoder_factory deprecated error

Tags: symfony4, symfony-3.2

I updated my website from Symfony 3.2 to Symfony 4, by creating a new symfony4 skeleton and moved the source code from symfony3.2 to symfony4.

I had been made the changes as mentioned in [Upgrading Symfony4](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html).Also I installed all the required packages.Now I can make routing and successfully got my web page on the display,the problem I am facing is login form doesn't work.

In my login controller for symfony3.2 version,

I used security.encoder_factory service

And when I am running it in symfony4 it results:

`The "security.encoder_factory" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.`

My controller code for encoding password is:

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    #$defaultEncoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('bcrypt', true, 5000);
    $defaultEncoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('bcrypt');

    $encoders = [
        User::class => $defaultEncoder, // Your user class. This line specify you ant sha512 encoder for this user class
        ];

    $encoderFactory = new EncoderFactory($encoders);

    $data = [
        'error' => null,
        '_username' => null,
    ];
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $_username = $request->request->get('_username');
        $_password = $request->request->get('_password');

        $data['_username'] = $_username;
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
            ->getRepository("App:User")
            ->findOneBy(array('username' => $_username);
        if (!$user) {
            $data['error']  = 'User-Id does not exist';
            return $this->render(
                'login.html.twig',
                $data
            );
        }

        $encoder = $encoderFactory->getEncoder($user);
        $salt = $user->getSalt();
        #$encoder = $this->encodePassword($_password, $salt);

        if (!$encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $encoder)) {
            $data['error'] = 'User-Id or Password not valid.';
            return $this->render(
                'login.html.twig',
                $data
            );
        } 

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('default__home_page'));
    }

    return $this->render(
        'login.html.twig',
     $data
    );
}
```

My security for encoding is:

```
security:
   encoders:
        App\Entity\User: bcrypt
        App\Security\User\WebserviceUser: bcrypt
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: bcrypt
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-    user-providers
    providers:
        #in_memory: { memory: ~ }
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: App:User
                property: username
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    secured_area:
        anonymous: ~
        pattern:    ^/s/login$
        http_basic: ~
        provider: fos_userbundle
        user_checker: security.user_checker

        form_login:
            login_path: login_page
            check_path: login_page
            failure_handler: security.authentication.failure_handler
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginControllerAuthenticator
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

        logout:
            path:   /logout/
            target: /login/
```

Is there any alternative way or service to encoding my password as the above code represents.

error:

```
No encoder has been configured for account "App\Entity\User".

  at vendor/symfony/security/Core/Encoder/EncoderFactory.php:51
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory->getEncoder(object(User))
     (src/Controller/Controller.php:65)
  at App\Controller\Controller->loginAction(object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:149)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:66)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:188)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:37)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See doc :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#the-password-encoder-factory

You can get encoder in you controller this way.

**EDIT :**

Here an example :

```
    $defaultEncoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('sha512', true, 5000);

    $encoders = [
      User::class => $defaultEncoder, // Your user class. This line specify you ant sha512 encoder for this user class
    ];

    $encoderFactory = new EncoderFactory($encoders);

    $user = new User('test', null); // The user you want to authenticate

    $password = $encoderFactory->getEncoder($user)->encodePassword('myPassword', 'mySalt');
```

---

**EDIT 2 :**

You have to defined YOUR user class there :

```
$encoders = [
    App\Entity\User::class => $defaultEncoder,
    ];
```

Check you're not using User Symfony class.

Comment: I didn't got cleared from the docs that why I am here...Can you suggest me how to overwrite the above code

Comment: I updated the code. If you have any question, tell me. You can post your user provider ?

Comment: I got error as `No encoder has been configured for account "App\Entity\User"` but I configured this in security.yaml

Comment: I updated my answer. Check your addind the encoder for YOUR user class.

Comment: Could it be that the encoder is configured in the yaml using bcrypt, and the MessageDigestPasswordEncoder is created in the controller using sha512?   Two different algorithms?